# Python how to update a dictionary with another dictionary by applying add to existing values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an existing dictionary with string keys and numerical values. I create another dictionary containing new keys and values which I need to `update` over the existing dictionary.

Only requirement is I need that if a key in new dictionary already exists in target dictionary, the value is added to existing value, instead of replacing it.

How can I achieve this in Python 2.7?

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: Please provide some sample code and expected output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a good case to use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d1 = Counter({'a':1,'b':1})
>>> d2 = Counter({'a':2,'c':3})
>>> d1.update(d2)
>>> d1
Counter({'a': 3, 'c': 3, 'b': 1})
```

You also can create new collection:

```
>>> d1 + d2
Counter({'a': 3, 'c': 3, 'b': 1})
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than the one I was writing. Kudos.